# wp_localize_scripts not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am totally stumped, it looks like everything should work... what am I missing?

```js
var tempUrl = myDir.theme_directory

smallbanners[0]='
<a target="_blank" href="'   +tempUrl+
'/showcase/absolue/absolue.html">
<img src"showcase/banners_small/absolue.jpg" 
class="smallbanners" alt="alt text"></a>'
```

```html
function wpdocs_6moons_scripts() {
    
    wp_enqueue_script('homebanners', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/homebanners.js');
    wp_localize_script('homebanners', 'myDir', array('theme_directory' => get_template_directory_uri()) );
    
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_6moons_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by adding these lines to the header.php of my theme

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myDir = {"theme_directory":"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/'; ?>"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/js/homebanners.js"></script>
```